# Self hosted servicestack redirects remote machines to localhost

Tags: servicestack

I've got a ServiceStack application that almost works when self hosted rather than to use IIS.

If I start the service and connect from a remote machine to the ip address of the PC `http://10.0.0.5:81` then it's fine and everything works as expected.

However if I start the service and the first connection happens to come in on localhost (say because I'm testing the service is working after it's been installed) then all remote machines get redirected to `http://localhost:81`.  The same is true if I used `127.0.0.1:81` with remote PC's getting redirected to the loop back address.

At that point all I can do is restart the service and connect from a remote machine first to get it working again.

Is there some way to disable what appears to be this caching?

Comment: Windows 7 64bit and Windows 8 64 bit,  "http://*:81/" is the start address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceStack tries to infer the `BaseUrl` for your services which it can only do at runtime which it then caches for subsequent requests. You can specify it to use an explicit Base Url instead with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { 
    WebHostUrl = "http://10.0.0.5:81",
});
```

Comment: That should do it once I've added it as a configurable option.  No way to just disable the caching so it will work for all locations?

Comment: @Saurbaum There isn't atm, the BaseUrl is stored in a static property and if caching was disabled than a concurrent request could change the BaseUrl for other requests.